# Discord.js: how do I get all the users who react to a message with a specific emoji, then set the list of users to a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

everyone! I am here because I am making a command that behaves in the style of [GiveawayBot](https://giveawaybot.party/): getting all users who react to a particular message, and picking random users from what users were found.

However, I am unsure on how I can go about this in **discord.js**. I plan to have the command ask for the message ID, the amount of users to pick, and the emoji the users should have reacted to.

Can I get some help on doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have no less than a few options:

- Listen to [messageReactionAdd](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) event to count up reactions as they happen live (and, possibly, [messageReactionRemove](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionRemove)).
- Use [message.awaitReactions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) or [message.createReactionCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) to query for your reactions of interest.
- [re-]fetch the individual message via [channel.fetchMessage](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage) and peek through its [.reactions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reactions).

Comment: What if the message is in a channel that's different from where I'm executing the command from? Would I need an additional argument that represents the channel to read the message from, or is there an easier method to that?

Comment: You could have the bot keep track of its message snowflakes, or use channel.fetchMessages to query them if they are about the only thing that your giveaways channel contains; you can look up the channel via guild.channels.find